# Outlook add-in which uses another add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

I have old outlook add-in (COM/VSTO). And I have new one with office.js. 
Is it possible to use old one from new one? 
Basically I want to imitate left click action on old plugin from new plugin code.

Thank you

Comment: As of tags for the question, I assume "New" add-in is the add-in is the add-in written with Office.js API, isn't it? Please clarify what is the "old" add-in? Is this COM/VSTO add-in or add-in which uses Office.js API, but written while back?

Comment: The old one is COM/VSTO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Office.js API doesn't have functionality to directly communicate to the COM/VSTO technology add-ins. You may share certain message data and/or user properties as described at [How to share user roaming settings between Outlook COM/VSTO and Office JS Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896769/how-to-share-user-roaming-settings-between-outlook-com-vsto-and-office-js-add-in), but nothing more.

If you have strong business case and this is something you would like to see in upcoming Office.js releases, you may post your suggestion at [officespdev.uservoice.com](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/filters/hot?category_id=131778)