# Detecting outlook add-ins

Tags: office-js, office-addins

We currently have a VSTO add-in for Outlook but want to write a new add-in so that we can run on all outlook platforms. However, we don't want our users to run both at the same time. Is it possible for the VSTO add-in to detect if there is a new style add-in installed and/or vice versa, can the new style add-in detect if the VSTO add-in is loaded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect if Office 365 addin is already active from a VSTO Outlook addin or vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562332/how-to-detect-if-office-365-addin-is-already-active-from-a-vsto-outlook-addin-or)

Comment: Yes, apologies. It is the same question.

Answer (score 1):

this capability doesn't exist at this time for Office JavaScript Add-ins, but we are considering it.

Can I ask you to log a uservoice item on https://officespdev.uservoice.com for it and we can track the feature request there?  Let me know when that is done.

Comment: Thanks Keyur, I have logged a uservoice item.