# Deploying both the VSTO and web Outlook add-ins at the same time

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have two Outlook add-ins.

The legacy VSTO add-in has more features but it's only available on the Outlook Windows desktop client.

The new JavaScript based web add-in is available on many more platforms. However, it doesn't have all the features of the VSTO add-in.

I can't find any information about disabling the web add-in for specific Outlook clients like Outlook for Windows.

What's the best way to go about deploying both these add-ins? The VSTO add-in should be favored. If it's enabled/installed, the web add-in should not be enabled.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is the maximum what you can do: [How to detect if Office 365 addin is already active from a VSTO Outlook addin or vice-versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562332/how-to-detect-if-office-365-addin-is-already-active-from-a-vsto-outlook-addin-or). There is no way to disable Office js add-in for specific client, as long as deployed will appear in every client supported.

Comment: Thank you @SlavaIvanov for the help. Until disabling the add-in for specific clients becomes possible, this will have to do.

Comment: Can you explain how you're deploying the Web Add-in? If it's through the Office store, you're looking to detect the VSTO add-in from the Web add-in rather than vice versa correct?

Comment: @MaviDomates Right now, I'm using [centralized deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment) to deploy and test the add-in but the plan is to eventually publish the add-in to the Office store.


And yes, you are right. The ideal situation for me is that I would be able to detect the VSTO add-in from the web add-in and disable the web add-in.


What Slava suggested won't fix my problem but at least I can maybe use the VSTO add-in to warn or notify the user if the web add-in is found.

Comment: You can't disable the web-addin as called out, but you can disable the VSTO addin. Alternatively, you can present a UI to the user where you'll show them how to disable the Web add-in in case you detect a VSTO addin. There are some further questions regarding this though, as I understand your question is primarily for Outlook client. What about the web experience? If you disable the Web add-in in Outlook client, it's also disabled in Outlook Web (Office 365 Web)

Comment: As I understand the situation, this is how the outlook add-ins work, the add-in manifest is installed on the user's mailbox and so the add-in will appear on all supported Outlook clients e.g. Outlook 2016, Outlook for Mac, Outlook on the Web.

As I said this is not an ideal situation in my case. What I really want to do but cannot is to enable the Outlook web add-in on all possible platforms **except**  the desktop Outlook application for Windows if the VSTO add-in is already installed because that would be redundant. I want the VSTO add-in to be favored because right now it's more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling add-ins for specific clients is not possible today. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page.
It looks like the feature you want has been requested by others already. Please upvote the existing [request](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/36215719-detecting-outlook-add-ins). Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

[Outlook Add-ins Engineering Team]