# Is it possible to delete the roaming data in a Outlook add-in?

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-web-addins

How can I delete the roaming settings saved using this command developing a Outlook add in?

```
Office.context.roamingSettings.set('username', username);
```

I readed that it is stored in a Json but where can I find it and delete it manually (without using the remove method)

Answer (score 1):

The location of an add-in's RoamingSettings properties has not been documented. It's most likely stored as a message in a hidden folder within the mailbox, but I've never been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

To delete roaming settings of your add-in you would need to write COM/VSTO add-in to reach the location or use [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) for this purpose. The settings bundle you are looking for is stored in the message property, which is stored in Associated contents table of the Inbox folder and may be accessed using IMAPIFolder interface. More information and screenshots on how exactly locate it over here: [How to share user roaming settings between Outlook COM/VSTO and Office JS Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896769/how-to-share-user-roaming-settings-between-outlook-com-vsto-and-office-js-add-in).