# How to set roaming settings for Outlook web addin for other mail boxes using EWS?

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

We are using the [JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/persisting-add-in-state-and-settings) from within an Outlook addin to set and get roaming settings for the addin.

According to the article linked above, it is possible to set those settings using EWS.  I have been unable to find any examples on how to do it.  What is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes and there are examples of doing so on the page you linked to eg https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.roamingsettings?view=office-js
2. Yes as the above link states

> They can be accessed by Exchange Web Services or Extended MAPI. They should not be used to store sensitive information such as user credentials or security tokens.

so you can write using EWS (or MAPI) to modify the underlying FAI item.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear.  I have tried to re-phrase it.  Do you have any ressources on how to do it with EWS?

Comment: I'd suggest you start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896769/how-to-share-user-roaming-settings-between-outlook-com-vsto-and-office-js-add-in which describes this in detail